# TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int' in blackjack game

Tags: python, list, function, random, blackjack

I am developing a blackjack game in python and am currently working on a function to deal cards but am receiving the following error "TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'". I have pasted the python code below.

```
import random
from numpy import random
def draw_card():
  '''
    This function will generate a random card from a deck of 52 cards
      - the suit is random, the card num is also random: 1-13 with equal opportunity 
      - input: none
      - return: String card_suit, Integer card_num
    '''     
  list_number=[]
  list_suit=[]
  card_number = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'A','J', 'Q', 'K']  #deck of cards
  suit = ['H','S','C','D']   #Type of suites

  for x in range(0,10):
    random.choice(1,52) #Generate a deck of 52 cards

    if card_number >= 1 and card_number <= 13:
      card_suit=suit[0]
      list_number.append(card_number)
      list_suit.append(card_suit)
    elif card_number >= 14 and card_number <= 26:
      card_suit=suit[1]  
      list_number.append(card_number)
      list_suit.append(card_suit)
    elif card_number >= 27 and card_number <= 39:
      card_suit=suit[2]
      list_number.append(card_number)
      list_suit.append(card_suit)
    elif card_number >= 40 and card_number <= 52:
      card_suit=suit[3]
      list_number.append(card_number)
      list_suit.append(card_suit)
```

```
# test
list_suit, list_number = draw_card()
print(list_suit, list_number)
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. `card_number` is a list. You can't compare it to a number. Also you should read the documentation for `random.choice` as that statement is currently not doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening because you are trying to compare a list with a number, which is obviously going to throw back an error.

Edit: also, you are using `random.choice` when you are supposed to use `random.randint`

What you need here is not to compare the numbers with the `card_number` variable.
Instead, you would want to store your `random.randint(1,52)` to a variable, and do your comparison using that variable.

```
newcard = random.randint(1,52) #Generate a deck of 52 cards

    if newcard >= 1 and newcard <= 13:
```

Comment: `random.choice()` does not work that way. `newCard` would always be ether 1 or 52, which does not seem to be intended here.

Comment: oops, you're right. The code should be `random.randint(1, 52)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You defined `card_number` as an array/list, which can't be compared to an integer value, as your error message says. That's is like saying "which one is bigger? 5 or [5, 4, 6, 8]. One is a number, the other a collection of numbers.

From your code, it looks like the value you are trying to compare is not actually `card_number`, but rather a random number between 1 and 52, which you try to get in `random.choice()`. However, you neither save the return value of that function in a variable, nor do you use it correctly. Check out [how to use it here](https://pynative.com/python-random-choice/). What you are actually looking for here is [`random.randrange()`](https://pynative.com/python-random-randrange/).

Also, you are appending `card_number` to `list_number`, which would result in a construct like this:

`[['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'A','J', 'Q', 'K'], ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'A','J', 'Q', 'K'], ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'A','J', 'Q', 'K'],['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', 'A','J', 'Q', 'K'], ...]`

So you would end up with an array of 10x `card_number` and another array with 10x `card_suit` which is porbably not what you are going for here.

### Sidenote

Rather than having this whole hassle with choosing a number between 1 and 52, you can simply get one element from `card_number` and one from `card_suit` respectively, with a function you already use: `random.choice()`.